# Groupby pandas dataframe and retain all the rows based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'xyz', 'xyz', 'cd'], 'col2':['2020-02-01', '2020-02-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01']})
df


    col1    col2
0   abc    2020-02-01
1   abc    2020-02-01
2   abc    2020-01-01
3   xyz    2020-01-01
4   xyz    2020-05-01
5   cd     2020-06-01
```

I want yo groupby based on col1 and keep all the rows of the max of col2

My Expected result:

```
    col1    col2
0   abc    2020-02-01
1   abc    2020-02-01
4   xyz    2020-05-01
5   cd     2020-06-01
```

I tried below code but it only gives me the row with max value of col2

```
df.sort_values('col2').groupby(['col1']).tail(1)
```

Comment: `df.sort_values('col2').drop_duplicates('col1', keep='last')`.

Comment: This will skip row 1 in the expected output I provided

Comment: `df[df['col2'] == df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('max')]`.